# Laser Printers: Widest Pantone Gamut?

Tags: color-management, printer, wide-gamut

Which laser printer models have the widest Pantone color gamut? -- old or new models are acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Printerinfo.com seem to measure gamut in their printer reviews.

For example they say the [HP CLJ3600n](http://www.printerinfo.com/content/HP-Color-LaserJet-3600n-Laser-Printer-Review/Photo-Performance.htm) "is not meant to print photographs, and this clearly shows."

Comment: Thanks; that review does contain a numeric measure of color error and of color gamut. But it doesn't have reviews for many printer models, even a common one like the HP 4600.

Answer (score 2):

Laser printers are not really known for their photo print quality or gamut. Ink jet printers have completely dominated this arena, and currently offer far wider print gamuts than you can get from other print technologies (especially from Epson and Canon). Current ink jet printers using UltraChrome HDR or Lucia EX support wide gamut up to Adobe RGB area, and cover over 90% of the Pantone solid color set.

If you absolutely must use a laser printer, then you will probably have to deal with a pretty small gamut, I would say sRGB range at best, but likely smaller than that.

Comment: appreciated, but I know and this doesn't address the question.

Comment: Sure it addresses the question. If you need *Pantone* gamut coverage (vs. just wide gamut...the two mean specific and distinct things), then a laser printer is not going to serve your needs. They aren't designed for that purpose, and never really have been. You might find a "wide gamut" laser, but that is not going to guarantee it covers much of the "pantone solid color set".